# get id from url parametrs (not from request)

Tags: python, django

How to get id from url parameters in django function `get_queryset`. Not from get request.

I have a url like so

http://127.0.0.1:8000/17/

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.NodesDetailView.as_view(), name='nodes_detail')
```

view

```
def get_queryset(self):
    node_id = self.request.
```

Comment: You posted a link to a local server, you will need to post it in an online server somewhere if you want us to actually be able to see the website

Comment: here link does not matter. I just showed example, from that example there is id, and i need get id in view, in `get_queryset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value from `self.kwargs`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    node_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since grouper from regex is getting passed in method this should work:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs['pk']
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
```